# Powershell Multiple Search/Condition Query

Tags: powershell, search

I am currently having an issue with finding multiple conditions within powershell. I am querying a text file, and am looking for a specific name, as well as a specific variable.  I am also trying to work from a top down approach via the text file.

The text file looks something like this:

```
Name1:
Nonsense
VariableA
VariableB
Nonsense
VariableC ==

Name2:
VariableA
Nonsense
VariableB ==
VariableC
```

I am trying to run a query to first find Name2, and then find the next line that contains both "Variable" and the "==" operator.  However, I have no idea where to start with these conditions.  If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
PS C:\> $txt = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.txt' | Out-String
PS C:\> $txt
Name1:
Nonsense
VariableA
VariableB
Nonsense
VariableC ==

Name2:
VariableA
Nonsense
VariableB ==
VariableC
PS C:\> $txt -match 'Name2[\s\S]*?(Variable.*?==)'
True
PS C:\> $matches[1]
VariableB ==
```

`Variable.*?==` matches the word "Variable" followed by "==" somewhere on the same line (the expression `.*?` matches anything except newlines). The preceding expression `[\s\S]*?` (shortest match of any character including newlines) makes sure that the next occurrence of the word "Version" after the word "Name2" is matched.

Comment: Worked like a charm Ansgar.  Thank you :)